# How to right-align Sign In button in Bootstrap NavBar with no toggle?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a header bar for my web site's sign up page using Twitter Bootstrap.  Per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) I'd like to replace the Brand with my website's name and then I'd like to put a Sign In button opposite it on the right-hand side of the navigation bar:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
      </div>

      <div class="pull-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><button type="submit" class="btn navbar-btn" >Sign In</button></li>
          </ul>     
      </div>          
  </nav>
</body>
```

I didn't put the "navbar-toggle collapsed" button in my code because I don't want the Sign In button to change to a toggle button on phones.  Instead, I would like to just display a Sign In button on the right-hand side of the navbar just as it does in a computer browser.  The problem I'm having is that the above code creates a tall two-row (or so) navbar on a phone with the Brand link in the upper left-hand corner and the Sign In button in the lower right-hand corner of the navbar.  How can I change this code so that the brand link and Sign In button are aligned opposite one another on the same row?  All the examples that show how to move a button to the left or right assume that you want to display a toggle button on phones.  I don't.  I want the Sign In button to appear on all devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are potentially many ways you could acheive this but I don't think it's possible out of the box as far as just relying on Bootstrap to handle it.

Simple solution, just position your **sign-in** button `absolutely`.

See Working Example:

```css
.navbar .login-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .login-btn {
    right: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Website Name</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn login-btn">Sign In</button>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked.  I'm new to Bootstrap and I haven't developed a sense yet as to what you can do in Bootstrap and what I have to do outside of it.  I really appreciate your help!